# Minecraft Bukkit Events

Tags: java, events, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to get into bukkit programming for minecraft, but for some reason I'm stuck with events. Here's my code:

Main class file:

```
package com.plugin1;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
//import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class Plugin extends JavaPlugin {

    public int songStage;
    public static Plugin plugin;

    public void OnEnable () {
        PluginDescriptionFile pluginDesc = getDescription();
        Logger logger = getLogger();

        plugin = this;
        registerEvents(this, new BlockBreak());

        logger.info(pluginDesc.getName() + " is enabled! (V. " + pluginDesc.getVersion() + ")");
    }

    public void OnDisable () {
        PluginDescriptionFile pluginDesc = getDescription();
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Plugin");

        plugin = null;
        logger.info(pluginDesc.getName() + " is disabled! (V. " + pluginDesc.getVersion() + ")");
    }

    public static void registerEvents(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin plugin, Listener... listeners) {
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(listener, plugin);
            }
        }

    public static Plugin getPlugin() {
        return plugin;
        }
   }
```

Event class file:

```
package com.plugin1;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockBreakEvent;

public class BlockBreak implements Listener {

    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGH)
    public void OnBlockBreak (BlockBreakEvent e) {  
        Player p = e.getPlayer();

        p.sendMessage("Block broken.");
    }
}
```

Basically, this returns no errors. I've gone through console and there's nothing. When I break a block, literally nothing happens!

I've tried a few of things: I've gone through it, tried multiple video tutorials and tried a text tutorial on the minecraft forums but still nothing. I also contacted a server owner who codes bukkit plugins, but he couldn't fix this...

If there's anyone who can help me with this, PLEASE LET ME KNOW!!!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If even some server owner deemed your code fine, then could it perhaps be a incorrectly setup compiler? Make sure to follow the instructions on how to set up Eclipse, as I heavily recommend it for the sake of minecraft modding

Comment: I've been running other code through it, like commands, but so far it's all been through one class file. However, the events didn't even work like that! And yes I use Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you aren't registering the Listeners in the right way...

Try this code and tell me if it works... I'm really wanting to help you

First of all don't use "Plugin" as the name for your Main Class... Use "Main" instead.

Enable:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getPluginManger().registerEvents(new Join(this),this);
    }

}
```

Listener:

```
public class Join implements Listener {

    private Main plugin;

    public Join(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent ev) {
        ev.setJoinMessage("Just another test");
    }
}
```

Hope it works...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code example to start the server in a process:

```
package me.Nightfighter001.GlobalSystem.Listener;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;

import me.Nightfighter001.GlobalSystem.Main.main;

public class Join implements Listener {

public Join(main main) {
    plugin = main;
    plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, main);
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent ev) {
    ev.setJoinMessage("");
}

main plugin = main.getPlugin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it really doesn't work. I think your Eventregistration isn't working. For my plugins I use this in the mainClass:

```
package me.Nightfighter001.GlobalSystem.Main;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.ConsoleCommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import me.Nightfighter001.GlobalSystem.Listener.Join;

public class main extends JavaPlugin {

public static main getPlugin() {
    return plugin;
}

private static main plugin;

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    plugin = this;

    new Join(this);

    ConsoleCommandSender console = Bukkit.getConsoleSender();
    console.sendMessage(new StringBuilder("\247c[\2476GlobalSystem\247c] \247bVersion \247c")
            .append(getDescription().getVersion()).append(" \247bdes Plugins wurde aktiviert!").toString());
    console.sendMessage(
            "\247c[\2476GlobalSystem\247c] \247bDieses Plugin darf nur benutzt werden, wenn der Entwickler \247cNightfighter001 \247bes erlaubt!");
    return;
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    ConsoleCommandSender console = Bukkit.getConsoleSender();
    console.sendMessage(new StringBuilder("\247c[\2476GlobalSystem\247c] \247bVersion \2474")
            .append(getDescription().getVersion()).append(" \247bdes Plugins wurde deaktiviert!").toString());
}
}
```

And in the EventClass:

```
package me.Nightfighter001.GlobalSystem.Listener;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;

import me.Nightfighter001.GlobalSystem.Main.main;

public class Join implements Listener {

public Join(main main) {
    plugin = main;
    plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, main);
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent ev) {
    ev.setJoinMessage("");
}

main plugin = main.getPlugin();
}
```

As you can see in my example I use the `PlayerJoinEvent`, but it also works with the `BlockBreakEvent`. I hope this helps :) And sorry for my bad English ;D

Comment: Then I really don't know what you are doing wrong... What IDE and which Bukkit oder Spigot -Version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you don't capitalize the names of the `onEnable` (and `onDisable`) methods. `onEnable` and `OnEnable` are two different methods since java is case sensitive, and since you're trying to override specific methods in the `JavaPlugin` super class, you'll need to spell them the exact same way.

Common convention is, as far as I know, that you start your methods with lowercase letters anyway though. The `@Override` annotation is very useful in catching these kinds of bugs, because it lets the compiler know that you mean to override an existing method, and if that method doesn't exist (for example if you misspelled the name or added different parameters), it will alert you (it also lets anyone reading the code immediately know you're overriding an existing method or implementing an interface).

Comment: That's right, but I also did it in my code and he/she said it didn't work :/

Comment: I tested this solution before posting here to make sure it was accurate (using Craftbukkit 1.8.7, API version 1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT). The code snippets posted in the question work just as intended when the name change to the `onEnable` method is made. I don't see any reason why the code wouldn't work with the corrections. The custom `registerEvents` method is correct and the questioner didn't specify exactly what he did with your code and what specifically didn't go as expected.