# @EventHandler never running for Bukkit Plugin

Tags: overriding, minecraft, bukkit, eventhandler

I am currently trying to get a bukkit plugin working. I run into this issue everytime and was wondering if anyone would know how to fix it. I have tried almost every fix you can google, so hopefully someone can share some light.

None of the player events ever work. When I do anything with a @EventHandler in front, it just doesn't run.
Here is an example:

```
package me.tgb20;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class pluginmain extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

    public void OnEnable(){
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    public void OnDisable(){
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void OnJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        p.sendMessage("Hello");
    }
}
```

When running this on the server, it never sees that a player has joined the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work if you don't capitalize the names of the onEnable (and onDisable) methods. **on**Enable and **On**Enable are two different methods since java is case sensitive, and since you're trying to override specific methods in the JavaPlugin super class, you'll need to spell them the exact same way.

Common convention is, as far as I know, that you start your methods with lowercase letters anyway though. The `@Override` annotation is very useful in catching these kinds of bugs, because it lets the compiler know that you mean to override an existing method, and if that method doesn't exist (for example if you misspelled the name or added different parameters), it will alert you (it also lets anyone reading the code immediately know you're overriding an existing method or implementing an interface).

(I copied this text from another [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687552/minecraft-bukkit-events/35691060#35691060) where someone had a very similar problem, although I don't believe this question counts as a duplicate).